# Determining the current AUTOCOMMIT DDL setting

Tags: sql, hana

With SET TRANSACTION AUTOCOMMIT DDL ON and SET TRANSACTION AUTOCOMMIT DDL OFF, you can set whether your session automatically commits after any DDL statement.

Is there a way to determine what you currently have it set to? I want to be able to write code that temporarily uses a certain value of the setting and then restores the original, or figure out whether I've accidentally been using the wrong setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is.
If the AUTOCOMMIT DDL has been set to OFF, then M_SESSION_CONTEXT contains the key
DDL_AUTO_COMMIT with value FALSE.

```
select key, value 
    from m_session_context 
where 
    connection_id = current_connection
and key ='DDL_AUTO_COMMIT';

KEY             VALUE
DDL_AUTO_COMMIT FALSE
```

So, if you don't find this record, the AUTOCOMMIT DDL mode is ON (default).

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future: [`current_connection`](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/dde16475191014bf3090e6b2e9857f/content.htm) is a built-in thing that gives the ID of your connection. You don't need to provide your connection ID as a query parameter or write a join against another table to get your ID or anything.